# Можно ли использовать код Python в приложении C#?

Tags: c#, python

Например, Рython при выполнении кода выдает некие значение, которые необходимо передать в C#.

Comment: @vater, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

А попробуйте-ка [Python for .NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pythonnet/), а лучше эту [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/)

Answer (score 4):

У вас отдельное приложение на python или просто кусок работающего кода? Если приложение, то реализуйте связь между приложениями на Python и C#, например, через json или SOAP. Если кусок кода - перепишите его на C#, это намного оптимальнее.